# Spring project, cannot instanciate my bluemix services

Tags: java, spring-boot, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson

I created a Web Apps with the starter pick Java Spring Basic. My project contains tree services : Language Translator, MongoDb, Push notifications.

I rewrite my code with the Spring technology and my maven install fails.

The error displayed :

> org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate
>   [com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.language_translator.v2.LanguageTranslator]:
>   Factory method 'languageTranslator' threw exception; nested exception
>   is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: okhttp3/RequestBody

I tried to connect to my Language Translator service with the command line and it worked fine.

```
package application;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

    @SpringBootApplication
    public class SBApplication {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(SBApplication.class, args);
        }
    }
```

My configuration class to instantiate my Language Translator Service

```
package application;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionalOnClass;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionalOnMissingBean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.language_translator.v2.LanguageTranslator;

    @Configuration
    @ConditionalOnClass(LanguageTranslator.class)
    public class LanguageTranslatorServiceConfig {


        @Value("${languagetranslator.username}")
        String username;
        @Value("${languagetranslator.password}")
        String password;


        @Bean
        @ConditionalOnMissingBean
        public LanguageTranslator languageTranslator() {
            LanguageTranslator language = new LanguageTranslator();
            language.setUsernameAndPassword(username, password);
            return language;
        }
    }
```

I also tried without the @ConditionalOnClass(LanguageTranslator.class) and @ConditionalOnMissingBean annotations. 
languagetranslator.username is declared in the application.properties file.

**Pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>projects</groupId>
    <artifactId>LanguageTranslatorApi</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Dalston.SR4</spring-cloud.version>

        <app.name>LanguageTranslatorApi</app.name>
    </properties>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.7.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- ADD -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!--  -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-hystrix</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.mobilefirstplatform.serversdk.java</groupId>
            <artifactId>push</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring connector -->
<!--         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-spring-service-connector</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-localconfig-connector</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-cloudfoundry-connector</artifactId>
        </dependency> -->

        <!-- WATSON SERVICES -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- PUSH NOTIFICATION -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.mobilefirstplatform.serversdk.java</groupId>
            <artifactId>push</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

And the name of my services are correctly written in the **manifest.yml**

```
---
applications:
- instances: 1
  timeout: 180
  name: LanguageTranslatorApi
  buildpack: java_buildpack
  path: ./target/LanguageTranslatorApi-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
  memory: 256M
  domain: mybluemix.net
  host: languagetranslator
  services:
    - languagetranslatorapi-imfpush-1511857545092
    - languagetranslatorapi-language-t-1511857521703
```

Listing errors :

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException:
>   Failed to instantiate
>   [com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.language_translator.v2.LanguageTranslator]:
>   Factory method 'languageTranslator' threw exception; nested exception
>   is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: okhttp3/RequestBody
>
> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'languageTranslator' defined in class
>   path resource [application/LanguageTranslatorServiceConfig.class]:
>   Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate
>   [com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.language_translator.v2.LanguageTranslator]:
>   Factory method 'languageTranslator' threw exception; nested exception
>   is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: okhttp3/RequestBody

Structure of my project  : Controller -> Ucc -> LanguageTranslatorService

```
    package application.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import application.business.Translator;
import application.business.dto.TranslatorDto;
import application.ucc.LanguageTranslatorUcc;

@RestController
public class LanguageController {

    private LanguageTranslatorUcc languageTranslatorUcc;

    @Autowired
    public LanguageController(LanguageTranslatorUcc languageTranslatorUcc) {
        this.languageTranslatorUcc = languageTranslatorUcc;
    }


    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST, value="/translate")
    public Translator translation(@RequestBody TranslatorDto translator) {
        System.out.println(translator.toString());
        return languageTranslatorUcc.translator(translator);
    }

}


package application.ucc.imp;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import application.business.Translator;
import application.business.dto.TranslatorDto;
import application.service.LanguageTranslatorService;
import application.ucc.LanguageTranslatorUcc;

@Service
public class LanguageTranslatorUccImpl implements LanguageTranslatorUcc{


    private LanguageTranslatorService languageTranslatorService;

    @Autowired
    public LanguageTranslatorUccImpl(LanguageTranslatorService languageTranslatorService) {
        this.languageTranslatorService = languageTranslatorService;
    }

    @Override
    public Translator translator(TranslatorDto translator) {

        return languageTranslatorService.translation("en-fr", translator);
    }

}


@Service
public class LanguageTranslatorServiceImpl implements LanguageTranslatorService{

    private LanguageTranslator languageTranslator;

    @Autowired
    public LanguageTranslatorServiceImpl(LanguageTranslator languageTranslator) {
        this.languageTranslator = languageTranslator;
    }

    @Override
    public Translator translation(String idModel, TranslatorDto translator) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}
```

How can i solve this ?

Comment: Okhttp3 is a compile dependency of the Watson SDK. Have you checked whether or not the okhttp3 libraries made it into the application?

Comment: @ebullient Yes the librairy is present. I have tried without the Configuration annotation and the install from Maven success but i cannot access to the LanguageTranslator when i try with the Authorized annotation, this error is displayed : 

Parameter 0 of constructor in application.service.impl.LanguageTranslatorServiceImpl required a bean of type 'com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.language_translator.v2.LanguageTranslator' that could not be found.

When i try to access with static method, i receives the Java null pointerException

Comment: @ebullient we have an spring-boot-starter that will probably help you here. See https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/spring-boot-starter